# How can I validate my drop down menu form in PHP

Tags: php

/* how can I validate a drop down menu in php. I am trying to validate if empty to go back and enter in a treatment. */

```
<div class="field">
     <label for="treatment">Treatment:</label>
       <select id="treatment" name="treatment" required>
        <option selected>Choose a treatment</option>
         <option value="Massage">Massage</option>
         <option value="Beeauty">Beauty</option>
         <option value="Reiki">Reiki</option>
         <option value="Meditation">Meditation</option>
         <option value="Workshops">Workshops</option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

/* my attempt so far doesn't work and I am confused by using REQUEST or POST also
I am trying to include three drop down lists in one line (sorry am a beginner) */

```
if (!isset($_POST['treatment']) && !isset($_POST['time']) && !isset($_POST['duration'])) {
echo "Please select treatment and  time.";
exit();
```

}

Comment: What do you wish to validate?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['treatment'])) { 
  echo 'Please select a Treatment.'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_REQUEST['treatment'])) 
{ 
  your code 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> if(isset($_REQUEST['treatment']) && ($_REQUEST['treatment'] != ""){
>
> Your code
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

you can easily put validation with javascript
>Choose a treatment
MassageBeauty
ReikiMeditation
Workshops

function validation(){ if(document.getElementById("games").value=="0"){ alert("Please select games");
        document.getElementById("games").focus(); return false; } return true;}